# Extendable card in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, extend, card

How can implement extendable card which extend over layout underneath not move it.
For example compose has card and column underneath. After click on card, extended card must hide column under extended card, not move it to bottom.

Comment: You mean dropdown menu?

Comment: yes, but i haven't drop down menu. I have surface with Row filed by loop according of state

Comment: I provided an answer that you can customize according to your project requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom `MyDropDown` Composable

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyDropdown(list: List<String>) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedText by remember { mutableStateOf(list[0]) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            expanded = expanded,
            onExpandedChange = {
                expanded = !expanded
            }
        ) {
            TextField(
                value = selectedText,
                onValueChange = {},
                readOnly = true,
                //trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
                // if you want icon
                modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor()
            )

            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
            ) {
                list.forEach { item ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(text = item) },
                        onClick = {
                            //selectedText = item
                            // i think you don't want change selected
                            expanded = false
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use like this

```
    setContent {
        MyTheme {
            val list = listOf<String>("A", "B", "C")
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp)
            ) {
                MyDropdown(list)
                MyDropdown(list)
                MyDropdown(list)
                MyDropdown(list)
            }
        }
    }
```